# Extracting information from OCR recognized text

Tags: java, android-studio, ocr

i'm currently trying to develop an Optical Character Recognition(OCR) apps which will pass the recognized data from the business card into my phone contact database.I already managed to recognized the data from the business card.

Project flowchart:

1. [Main Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVWyz.png).The user will have to click "Take Picture" button to take picture using the camera.

2.The recognized text from the business card will be shown like those texts under the "Take Picture" button.

3. Then the user will have to click "SAVE TO CONTACTS" button to save the contact information in the phone contact database.The contact name,contact number and email address from the recognized text will be passed into the respected [contact information fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2mZ1.png) in my phone contact database

Recognition code using OCR(Main Menu):

```js
package com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.media.ExifInterface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class SimpleAndroidOCRActivity extends Activity {
  public static final String PACKAGE_NAME = "com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple";
  public static final String DATA_PATH = Environment
    .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/SimpleAndroidOCR/";

  // You should have the trained data file in assets folder

  public static final String lang = "eng";

  private static final String TAG = "SimpleAndroidOCR.java";

  protected Button _button;
  // protected ImageView _image;
  protected EditText _field;
  protected String _path;
  protected boolean _taken;

  protected static final String PHOTO_TAKEN = "photo_taken";

  Button button2; //step 1


  @
  Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    String[] paths = new String[] {
      DATA_PATH, DATA_PATH + "tessdata/"
    };

    for (String path: paths) {
      File dir = new File(path);
      if (!dir.exists()) {
        if (!dir.mkdirs()) {
          Log.v(TAG, "ERROR: Creation of directory " + path + " on sdcard failed");
          return;
        } else {
          Log.v(TAG, "Created directory " + path + " on sdcard");
        }
      }

    }

    // lang.traineddata file with the app (in assets folder)


    if (!(new File(DATA_PATH + "tessdata/" + lang + ".traineddata")).exists()) {
      try {

        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        InputStream in = assetManager.open("tessdata/" + lang + ".traineddata");
        //GZIPInputStream gin = new GZIPInputStream(in);
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(DATA_PATH + "tessdata/" + lang + ".traineddata");

        // Transfer bytes from in to out
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        //while ((lenf = gin.read(buff)) > 0) {
        while ((len = in .read(buf)) > 0) {
          out.write(buf, 0, len);
        } in .close();
        //gin.close();
        out.close();

        Log.v(TAG, "Copied " + lang + " traineddata");
      } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Was unable to copy " + lang + " traineddata " + e.toString());
      }
    }

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2); //step 2


    // _image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    _field = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.field);
    _button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    _button.setOnClickListener(new ButtonClickHandler());

    _path = DATA_PATH + "/ocr.jpg";
  }
  public void onClickbutton2(View v) //step 3
    {
      startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.BUTTON2"));
    }



  public class ButtonClickHandler implements View.OnClickListener {
    public void onClick(View view) {
      Log.v(TAG, "Starting Camera app");
      startCameraActivity();
    }
  }

  // Simple android photo capture:
  // http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/03/simple-android-photo-capture/

  protected void startCameraActivity() {
    File file = new File(_path);
    Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

    final Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
  }

  @
  Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    Log.i(TAG, "resultCode: " + resultCode);

    if (resultCode == -1) {
      onPhotoTaken();
    } else {
      Log.v(TAG, "User cancelled");
    }
  }

  @
  Override
  protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putBoolean(SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.PHOTO_TAKEN, _taken);
  }

  @
  Override
  protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState()");
    if (savedInstanceState.getBoolean(SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.PHOTO_TAKEN)) {
      onPhotoTaken();
    }
  }

  protected void onPhotoTaken() {
    _taken = true;

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 4;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_path, options);

    try {
      ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(_path);
      int exifOrientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
        ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

      Log.v(TAG, "Orient: " + exifOrientation);

      int rotate = 0;

      switch (exifOrientation) {
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
          rotate = 90;
          break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
          rotate = 180;
          break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
          rotate = 270;
          break;
      }

      Log.v(TAG, "Rotation: " + rotate);

      if (rotate != 0) {

        // Getting width & height of the given image.
        int w = bitmap.getWidth();
        int h = bitmap.getHeight();

        // Setting pre rotate
        Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
        mtx.preRotate(rotate);

        // Rotating Bitmap
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, false);
      }

      // Convert to ARGB_8888, required by tess
      bitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    } catch (IOException e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't correct orientation: " + e.toString());
    }

    // _image.setImageBitmap( bitmap );

    Log.v(TAG, "Before baseApi");

    TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
    baseApi.setDebug(true);
    baseApi.init(DATA_PATH, lang);
    baseApi.setImage(bitmap);

    String recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();

    baseApi.end();

    // You now have the text in recognizedText var, you can do anything with it.
    // We will display a stripped out trimmed alpha-numeric version of it (if lang is eng)
    // so that garbage doesn't make it to the display.

    Log.v(TAG, "OCRED TEXT: " + recognizedText);

    if (lang.equalsIgnoreCase("eng")) {
      recognizedText = recognizedText.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", " ");
    }

    recognizedText = recognizedText.trim();

    if (recognizedText.length() != 0) {
      _field.setText(_field.getText().toString().length() == 0 ? recognizedText : _field.getText() + " " + recognizedText);
      _field.setSelection(_field.getText().toString().length());
    }

  }


}
```

Add contacts information fields:

```js
package com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple;


import android.content.ContentProviderOperation;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.OperationApplicationException;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.media.ExifInterface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.RawContacts;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;


public class Contacts extends AppCompatActivity {

  EditText edtTxtContactName, edtTxtContactNumber, edtTxtContactEmail;
  ImageView imgContactPhoto;
  Button btnAddContact;
  View view;
  String imagePath = null;
  Uri uri;
  ExifInterface exif;
  boolean isButtonClicked = false;
  View snackView;
  Bitmap rotateBitmap;
  InputMethodManager inm;
  public static boolean isUpdate;
  String cID, cName, cNumber, cEmail; //
  Bitmap cPhoto;
  public boolean FLAG = true;
  Button button3;

  @
  Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_contact_activity_main);

    view = findViewById(R.id.rootView);

    edtTxtContactName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtTxtContactName);
    edtTxtContactNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtTxtContactNumber);
    edtTxtContactEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtTxtContactEmail);

    imgContactPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgContactPhoto);

    btnAddContact = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddContact);
    inm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

    if (isUpdate) {
      cID = getIntent().getExtras().getString("cID");
      cName = getIntent().getExtras().getString("cName");

      cNumber = getIntent().getExtras().getString("cNumber"); //
      cEmail = getIntent().getExtras().getString("cEmail");
      cPhoto = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("cPhoto");
      btnAddContact.setText(getString(R.string.update_contact));
      edtTxtContactName.setText(cName);
      edtTxtContactNumber.setText(cNumber); //
      edtTxtContactEmail.setText(cEmail);
      imgContactPhoto.setImageBitmap(cPhoto);
      FLAG = false;

    } else {
      btnAddContact.setText(getString(R.string.add_contact));
    }
    btnAddContact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@
      Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

        if (btnAddContact.getText().toString().equals(getString(R.string.add_contact))) {

          if (edtTxtContactName.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
            Snackbar.make(v, "You must provide name.", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("OK", new View.OnClickListener() {@
              Override
              public void onClick(View v) {

              }
            }).show();
          } else if (edtTxtContactNumber.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
            Snackbar.make(v, "You must provide number.", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("OK", new View.OnClickListener() {@
              Override
              public void onClick(View v) {

              }
            }).show();
          } else {
            isButtonClicked = true;
            snackView = v;
            inm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
            addContact();
          }
        } else if (btnAddContact.getText().toString().equals(getString(R.string.update_contact))) {
          String strName = edtTxtContactName.getText().toString();
          String strNumber = edtTxtContactNumber.getText().toString();
          String strEmail = edtTxtContactEmail.getText().toString();
          imgContactPhoto.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
          Bitmap bitmap = imgContactPhoto.getDrawingCache();

          if (updateContact(cID, strName, strNumber, strEmail, bitmap)) {
            Snackbar.make(v, "Contact updated successfully.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          } else {
            Snackbar.make(v, "Failed to update contact.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }

        } else {
          Snackbar.make(v, "Some internal error occured, Please try after some time.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

      }
    });

    imgContactPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@
      Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        selectImage();
      }
    });

  }
  public void onClickbutton3(View v) //step 3
    {
      startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.BUTTON3"));
    }

  private void selectImage() {
    final CharSequence[] option = {
      "Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery"
    };
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
      Contacts.this);
    builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
      new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {@
        Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {}
      });
    builder.setItems(option, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

      @
      Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

        if (option[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
          clickPhotoFromCamera();
        } else if (option[item].equals("Choose from Gallery")) {
          uploadPhotoFromCamera();
        }
      }

    });
    builder.show();
  }

  private void clickPhotoFromCamera() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";
    File imageStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), imageFileName);
    uri = Uri.fromFile(imageStorageDir);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

  }

  private void uploadPhotoFromCamera() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
  }

  @
  Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
      if (requestCode == 1) {
        imagePath = uri.getPath();
        displayImageBitmap(imagePath);
      } else if (requestCode == 2) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePath = {
          MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA
        };
        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePath,
          null, null, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
        String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
        c.close();
        displayImageBitmap(picturePath);
      }
    }
  }

  public void displayImageBitmap(String image_path) {
    File mediaFile = new File(image_path);
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mediaFile.getAbsolutePath());
    int height = (myBitmap.getHeight() * 512 / myBitmap.getWidth());
    Bitmap scale = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, 512, height, true);
    int rotate = 0;
    try {
      exif = new ExifInterface(mediaFile.getAbsolutePath());
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);
    switch (orientation) {
      case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
        rotate = 0;
        break;
      case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
        rotate = 270;
        break;
      case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
        rotate = 180;
        break;
      case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
        rotate = 90;
        break;
    }

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(rotate);
    rotateBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scale, 0, 0, scale.getWidth(), scale.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    imgContactPhoto.setImageBitmap(rotateBitmap);
  }

  public void addContact() {
    ArrayList < ContentProviderOperation > insertOperation = new ArrayList < ContentProviderOperation > ();
    int rawContactID = insertOperation.size();

    // Adding insert operation to operations list
    // For insert a new raw contact in the ContactsContract.RawContacts
    insertOperation.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
      .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
      .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
      .build());
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    if (rotateBitmap != null) { // If an image is selected successfully
      rotateBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 75, stream);

      // For insert Photo in the ContactsContract.Data
      insertOperation.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.IS_SUPER_PRIMARY, 1)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, stream.toByteArray())
        .build());

      try {
        stream.flush();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
    // For insert display name in the ContactsContract.Data
    insertOperation.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
      .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
      .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
      .withValue(StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, edtTxtContactName.getText().toString())
      .build());
    // For insert Mobile Number in the ContactsContract.Data
    insertOperation.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
      .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
      .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
      .withValue(Phone.NUMBER, edtTxtContactNumber.getText().toString())
      .withValue(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
      .build());
    // For insert Work Email in the ContactsContract.Data
    insertOperation.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
      .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
      .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
      .withValue(Email.ADDRESS, edtTxtContactEmail.getText().toString())
      .withValue(Email.TYPE, Email.TYPE_WORK)
      .build());
    try {
      // Executing all the insert operations as a single database transaction
      getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, insertOperation);
      if (isButtonClicked == true) {
        edtTxtContactName.setText("");
        edtTxtContactNumber.setText("");
        edtTxtContactEmail.setText("");
        imgContactPhoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_contact);
        Snackbar.make(snackView, "Contact added successfully", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("Hide", new View.OnClickListener() {@
          Override
          public void onClick(View v) {

          }
        }).show();
      } else {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Contact is successfully added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
      }

    } catch (RemoteException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  boolean updateContact(String contactID, String contactName, String contactNumber, String contactEmailAdd, Bitmap bitmap) {
    ArrayList < ContentProviderOperation > ops = new ArrayList < > ();
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
      .newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
      .withSelection(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?", new String[] {
        contactID, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
      })
      .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, contactName)
      .build());

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
      .newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
      .withSelection(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=? AND " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE + "=?", new String[] {
        contactID, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, String.valueOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
      })
      .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, contactNumber)
      .build());
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
      .withSelection(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=? AND " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE + "=?", new String[] {
        contactID, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, String.valueOf(Email.TYPE_WORK)
      })
      .withValue(Email.ADDRESS, contactEmailAdd)
      .build());
    try {
      ByteArrayOutputStream image = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, image);

      ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
        .withSelection(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=? AND " +
          ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?", new String[] {
            contactID, Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
          })
        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.IS_SUPER_PRIMARY, 1)
        .withValue(Photo.PHOTO, image.toByteArray())
        .build());

      /*Builder builder;
      builder = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
      builder.withSelection(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?" + " AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?",
              new String[]{contactID, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE});
      builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, image.toByteArray());
      ops.add(builder.build());*/
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
      getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  @
  Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add_contact_menu, menu);

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_save);
    if (FLAG) {
      item.setVisible(true);
      this.invalidateOptionsMenu();
    } else {
      item.setVisible(false);
      this.invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
    return true;
  }

  @
  Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
      return true;
    }
    switch (id) {
      case android.R.id.home:
        onBackPressed();
        return true;

    }
    if (id == R.id.action_save) {

      if (edtTxtContactName.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You must provide name.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

      } else if (edtTxtContactNumber.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You must provide number.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

      } else {
        inm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
        isButtonClicked = false;
        addContact();
      }

      return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }

  @
  Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
  }
}
```

The problem is i do not know how to separate each text from the recognized texts with respect to name, contact number,email address **and** pass them into those fields in my contact database.

The business card structure/format is not specific, its bit of difficult to assume.However few things assume:

1. "@" containing string mostly going to be email id.
2. All digits with braces or + sign mostly going to be phone number.

Comment: did you checked: http://www.guidingtech.com/11155/extract-text-from-picture-ocr-google-docs-drive-android/

Comment: As i already stated in my post,i already can recognized the text from the business card.The problem is i do not know how to extract the important information from the recognized text such as name,phone number and email address to be passed into my phone contact database @piotrek1543

Comment: @HelpMeSenpai can you share your layout file ??

Answer (score 1):

The process of searching for, properly locating and extracting specific values from text is called parsing. As you stated, it is sometimes based on assumptions, such as if "@" is present then that string is an e-mail.

Robustness of your parsing code can be improved with redundancy and adaptive decision making. For example: locating the string containing "@" signifies an e-mail address. Then also looking for "Email" or "E-mail" label can either confirm the previously found result, or it can find a missing e-mail address, in case "@" was misrecognized by OCR and could not be found in the first search.

Assuming that OCR is rarely 100% accurate, especially on such complex document type as a business card (due to small font, skewed pictures, colors and backgrounds, artistic fonts) is a good rule, requiring redundancy and special case handling.

False positives may also be present, such as "@" can be found in a string that is not an e-mail address, for example in a Twitter handle like "@YourTwitterName". Your parsing code can be improved with exclusion of predictable false positives.